# Is there a preferred way to ask about first hand experience?

Tags: discussion

There are a lot of questions with factual answers that can be researched online. I can go through travel forums and come up with what I think is a valid conclusion based on what people say.

One of the key values of Travel.SE for me is that I can ask for people that have first hand experience. It really means a lot more to me if someone with an established reputation here can answer a question based on experience (as opposed to researching or using second hand information).

So the crux of my question is if there is a preferred way for asking for first-hand experience?

Here's an [example question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6766/what-are-the-standard-border-checks-when-traveling-between-warsaw-and-berlin-by). I see the reference online, but want to know from someone who has recently made this crossing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question could simply be "does anyone have first-hand experience with x".  The benefit of a site like this is that the people on here usually enjoy talking about their experiences, and if they see one like that they'll likely be happy to help.  There's no specific way of asking - it all depends on what you're after - but really as we've seen with some of the more vague questions - the more detail about what you want as an answer, the better.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll phrase things that way. Wasn't sure if being over specific was a problem. Really excited about this community, I travel a ton so I'm hoping to get to know the people here.